# Free light OUTBOUND SMTP program for Windows servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, smtp

anyone know of any free SMTP outbound only servers / service for a windows server 2008 machine? I've got some web pages that send out emails (around 300 a day).

I don't want any inbound stuff / mail boxes, bad mail, etc.

just outbound and any failed messages can go into a log file or something.

anyone have any suggestions?

I'm not sure if the iis smtp service is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in SMTP server, you can't get lighter than that, especially if IIS is already running. I'm not sure what you mean by sufficient - as you say, your requirements are minimal.

You don't need to accept mail from anything other than the local machine. Be careful that your web pages can't be used to relay mail, but that issue is independent of your choice of SMTP server.

As for badmail, retries etc, anyone else got some configuration ideas? I would try to minimize the number of retries, and either send badmail to NULL somehow, or schedule a script to clean out the directory periodically.

Comment: Ok, i've installed the service and used telnet to send some mail. works. nice. bummer that my code doesn't work (it works great when i use an external SMTP provider .. which i want to move off). doh! wish there was also some more helpful event log / error log information...

Comment: Found the error :) i had a custom app.config entry => email = off. lols. slap!

Answer (score 0):

You can download EmiaCtrlLite, a free POP3/SMTP client COM Component @ http://www.system-engine.com.